# If my server has multiple IP addresses, how can I run a script using each of the IP addresses?

Tags: php, ip

Let's say my server has 10 IP addresses.

I'd like to run the same PHP script 10 times, but each time use a different one of the IP addresses. The PHP script would be accessing the internet.

Is something like this possible? (using a different IP each time)

If so, can you point me in the right direction of being able to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: The answer boils down to - how does your server "get" those 10 IP addresses? That should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can choose which interface you bind to:

```
$options = array(
    'socket' => array(
        'bindto' => '192.168.0.12:0',
     ),
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);

/* Sends an http request to www.example.com through local interface 192.168.0.12:0 */
$fp = fopen('http://www.example.com', 'r', false, $context);
fpassthru($fp);
fclose($fp);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php

Comment: If I don't want to change the code, or I'm using a binary, how to run a script from command line selecting a specific IP address for outgoing requests? I want to change the ip only for that command or shell session

Comment: @MarcoMarsala, that depends greatly on the binary. If the binary has IP addresses hard-coded, you can't change them. If the binary allows you to use a command-line parameter to choose the IP addresss, then you can do so. You'll have to check the documentation of your binary.

Comment: I've found a solution, I use ip route to change ip for the current session

Comment: @bleemboy could you please post your solution? I want to use it for curl